# Drop down-menu on ListView for Android 

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm new to android development, and I would like to do a drop down menu like in Maps application.

schema :

[image]

For example, if I click on the third item I'll have more informations about my Item thing, and one or two buttons to launch another activity.

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [Expandable ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) may be suitable to your problem.

Here is the best example given: http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html

Comment: Glad about your reply that answer has helped you exactly. And Welcome to StackOverflow...:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use expandable list view.refer following link.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html